# Updated VPS. Increase RAM?

Tags: php, debian

I just got my VPS server updated, with CPU increased, and RAM increased from 1GB to 16GB. However, I don't see any improvements in performance. The queries is still running slow. Do I need to update some files to take advantage of the new performance?

It's a Linux, debian server, with apace2 and phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: good hardware is no substitute for good code - bad code can break any amount of hardware you throw at it.

Comment: if you have some code that's not working well post a thread about that - as it stands this is not an answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally more RAM makes the MySQL server faster. Check the MySQL server configuration, Oracle offers support as well. Just call them they're often helpful.

Comment: More RAM doesn't make MySQL faster if you don't configure it properly, though.

Comment: @ceejayoz: That's exactly what I wrote / meant.

Comment: More RAM only makes MySQL faster if that's where the bottleneck is. If you've got 1TB of RAM and a crappy 5400 RPM disk, you should probably upgrade the disk.